# Можно ли с RxJava2 получить свой обьект?

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Хочу разобраться с rx и вот такой вопрос у меня сейчас есть у меня такой метод

```
private boolean isThereBlanksForSing()
{
    boolean result = false;

    for (CallServiceCode tmpCode : mServiceCodeArrayList)
    {
        if (getServiceCodeFormStatus(tmpCode).isUnanswered())
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Тут я проверяю обьекты в списке и если есть такой который соответствует условию, то возвращаю соответствующее значение

И вот не могу понять как правильно написать тоже самое только в Rx стиле

что то типо такого

```
return Observable.fromIterable(mServiceCodeArrayList)//
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                     .filter(iServiceCode -> getServiceCodeFormStatus(iServiceCode).isUnanswered()) //
                     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                     .subscribe();
```

только нужно еще как то проверить есть `size() > 0`, то вернуть `true` или я знаю, что есть метод который ищет первое совпадение типо `findFirst()`

В обшем как это правильно сделать.

Или я просто не правильно понимаю как работать с рх ?

Подскажите кто работает с этим как бы вы это сделали, когда есть список обьектов и нужно проверить соответствует хоть какой то обьект в этом списке вашему условию?

Если есть вопросы пишите

**ПРАВКА**

```
private boolean isThereBlanksForSing()
{

    return = Observable.fromIterable(mServiceCodeArrayList)//
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) //
              .filter(iServiceCode -> getServiceCodeFormStatus(iServiceCode).isUnanswered()) //
              .isEmpty()//
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //
              .subscribe(isThereBlanksForSing ->
              {
                  // chetrue or false
              });


}
```

Comment: То, что вы хотите - невозможно сделать используя RX. Observsble не может что-то возвращать, как функция. Он просто выполняет какие то действия и преобразование на потоке данных. В вашем случае, проще использовать вашу обычную функцию `isThereBlanksForSing`. Так будет удобнее и меньше кода чем с RX. Это не тот случай, когда RX вам облегчит жизнь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы проверить осталось ли что-то после фильтра, можно воспользоваться оператором `isEmpty()`. Он вернёт `Observable<Boolean>`, который эмитит `true` только тогда, когда `Observable`, на котором он был вызван завершается не отдав ни одного элемента:

```
Observable.fromIterable(mServiceCodeArrayList)
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
         .filter(iServiceCode -> getServiceCodeFormStatus(iServiceCode).isUnanswered())
         .isEmpty()
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(isThereBlanksForSing -> {
                 // chetrue or false
         });
```

Ещё есть оператор [Contains](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/contains.html). Работает по типу `contains()` в коллекциях. Но похоже для вашего случая он не подходит.

Comment: Ваш ответ не до конца верный, так как он делает не совсем то же самое , что и мой метод который в вопросе, написаный на джаве. Разница в том, что если изначально `mServiceCodeArrayList.size() == 0` , то в моем случае цикл не будет выполняться и в итоге я получу `false` , а в вашем примере `filter()` отработает на изначально пустом списке и когда дойдет дело до `isEmpty()` , то конечно он вернет `true` ... как это можно исправить?

Comment: И так же я добавил правку в вопрос, скажите , можно ли сделать, что то типо такого как я там показал, чтоб в `return` что то возвращать? Или так rx не работает?

Comment: В моём ответе результат будет противоположный вашему. То есть если у вас `true` то у меня `false` и наоборот. Просто инвертируйте булеан перед использованием. По поводу `return` да, rx так не работает. Из функции вы можете вернуть `Observable<Boolean>`, полученный после `isEmpty()`, на который подпишитесь где-то в другом месте. Но сам результат вы можете получить только в методе `subscribe()`.

Comment: Либо если потом примените к нему другие операторы map, flatMap и т.д. Советую серию статей [Грокаем* RxJava](http://habrahabr.ru/post/265269). Она правда по RxJava1, но основы rx, описанные там не сильно изменились во второй версии.